# Class constructor acts strange

Tags: c++

In this way

```cpp
#include <sstream>

void f(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello";
}
```

Everything went fine. But in this way, with an extra brackets

```cpp
#include <sstream>

void f(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss();
    ss << "hello";
}
```

I got a compiler error:

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'std::stringstream() {aka std::basic_stringstream<char>()}' and 'char' to binary 'operator<<'
```

How is that?

Comment: `stringstream ss();` declares a *function* by the name of `ss`, which takes no arguments and returns a `stringstream` by value.

Comment: By the way, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question, for example to include the *actual* error you get from the [mcve] you show.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, that's very important, I found that I missed the `std::`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old problem in C++.

```
stringstream ss();
```

could be interpreted in two ways. As a declaration of an object `ss` of type `stringstream` using the default constructor, or of a function `ss` returning `stringstream` and taking no parameters.

The compiler chooses the function declaration, which here (and, in my experience, usuaully) is not what the programmer intended.

Solutions are either to miss off the brackets for default construction:

```
stringstream ss;
```

Or use the C++ curly brace initialization:

```
stringstream ss{};
```